# Cannot retrieve the right documents from MongoDB collection

Tags: json, mongodb, mongosh

I am trying to retrieve some documents from a MongoDB collection (called `expenses`).

Here you are the entire database, obtained using `db.expenses.find()`:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("65708c6237b62067296a398f"),
    date: '2013-10-21T13:28:06.419z',
    description: 'playstation',
    category: 'miscellaneous',
    cost: 499,
    users: [ { username: 'Giacomo', amount: 499 } ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("6570950cecb7eb1b4b868409"),
    date: '2013-10-21T13:28:06.419z',
    description: 'tennis court',
    category: 'sport',
    cost: 100,
    users: [
      { username: 'prova', amount: 50 },
      { username: 'Giacomo', amount: 50 }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("6570953aecb7eb1b4b86840a"),
    date: '2013-10-21T13:28:06.419z',
    description: 'netflix subscription',
    category: 'entertainment',
    cost: 100,
    users: [ { username: 'prova', amount: 10 } ]
  }
]
```

I need to retrieve just the documents that have an object with `username: 'Giacomo'` inside of the array `users`.

For instance, in this case, the retrieved documents should be the first and the second (the third has not `username: 'Giacomo'` in the array).

My problem is that I cannot find the right query for obtaining such a result.

Thank you in advance for your time and patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with a simple `find()`:

```js
db.expenses.find({'users.username': 'Giacomo'});
```

See [Specify a Query Condition on a Field in an Array of Document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#specify-a-query-condition-on-a-field-in-an-array-of-documents) using dot notation.

Answer (score 1):

Use $[elemMatch](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) for this target:

```
    db.collection.aggregate({
      "$match": {
        "users": {
          $elemMatch: {
            username: "Giacomo"
          }
        }
      }
    })
```

See [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xY5vX8omhOU).